# Pentaho step failing because of multiple rows

Tags: oracle

I have a pentaho flow with an input step with query

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE userno=?`

which get's the parameter(userno) from a previous step- `copy rows to result`.

However I get this error :

`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

after the transformation has executed for a while. I suspect it's because the result has more than one row of which I need all for the next step. Don't know what's causing this issue cause my query is not a subquery. Any help?

Comment: You can restrict the number of rows to 1 using rownum function. But you need to make sure that in all the case you need only 1 row. like `SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE userno=? and rownum < 2;`

Comment: In some cases I'll need more than 1 row

Comment: rownum < 2 without ORDER BY is meaningless @XING

Comment: @RaymondNijland `Order by ?` Do you  know that ? I guess OP didnot ever mention what is actually needed. My comment was restricted to have just 1 row(whichever it comes irrespetive if any order).

Comment: I know ROWNUW < 2 limits to only 1 row. A query with ROWNUM < 2 without a ORDER BY can return random records because the return order is not fixed without a ORDER BY.. i should said this in the last comment off mine.  @XING

Comment: It smells like a issue with the data. Does `SELECT userno, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY userno HAVING count(*)>1` return any row?

Comment: By `pentaho`, I guess you mean `pentaho-data-integrator`. Well are you sure the error `ORA-01427` is thrown by the `Input table`step?

Comment: yes `SELECT userno, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY userno HAVING count(*)>1` return rows...
and yes I mean pentaho data integrator

Comment: The error has got nothing to do with Pentaho. Hence removing the tag